# can government (US/UK) simply declare agreements to pay in crypto null&void?

Tags: contract-law

I have no expertise in this, but as a layman I've been thinking about the ways in which governments can destroy the value of cryptocurrencies if they really want to do so.

In China, all cryptocurrency transactions are considered illegal. India has flirted with the idea of a ban, though it isn't clear whether the Indian government go ahead with such a ban.

If in the US/UK there were a political consensus to discourage the use of cryptocurrencies, what could the government do? Short of having a full ban (which wouldn't be popular), could they for instance make a new law saying that all agreements in which A agrees to pay B in cryptocurrencies are no longer legally binding?

Answer (score 1):

### in general: yes

The government of a country is free to ban anything the constitution of its own country does not prevent it from banning. No constitution anywhere decrees that you have a right to cryptocurrency. So any government could declare it valueless and ban its trade and possession in its country.

### [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

While the constitution of the US bans it to prevent banning *all* arms (2nd amendment) or enacting censorship (1st amendment), nothing in the constitution establishes a right to cryptocurrency. The only amendment that would be relevant is that in banning it, there needs to be **due process of law** under the fourteenth amendment in depriving them of property. This can be most easily done by declaring a cutoff date after which usage and possession of cryptocurrency is made illegal.

But does the federal government have power? It does. Any transaction on the internet automatically is Interstate commerce, thus the [commerce clause](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/commerce_clause) applies and as a result, federal laws apply. The same paragraph vests all decisions on minting and the shape of minting with the US Congress in [Art. I, S.8 c.5](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S8-C5-1/ALDE_00001066/). Most relevant:

> The Congress shall have Power ... to regulate commerce with foreign nations, and among the several states, and with the Indian tribes.

They can ban the trade of Cryptocurrency across state lines under that clause just as much as they could have banned trading alcohol. They went for the 18th amendment instead, because that banned intra-state sales too. Since the servers where cryptocurrency is stored are usually *not* in your state, in fact not even the US usually, such transactions fall under the commerce clause and federal law.

Comment: Is this actually the case for the USA at least?  The US Constitution enumerates some things that the government cannot do as well as some things it can do.  But there is also the 10th Amendment: "The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people."

Comment: Currency is federal, see Art. I, S8 c5.

Comment: @jwh20 show me how they'd be banned when they crack out the commerce clause, or taxation power - which could be used to leverage a 100% tax on receiving any cryptocurrency to de-facto ban it.

Comment: I doubt that it would go unchallenged.  Yes, US currency is federal but crypto is not US currency.

Comment: @jwh20 so is *canabis*, but the US could ban its trade under... *drumroll* [commerce clause](https://ylpr.yale.edu/inter_alia/sleeping-giant-how-dormant-commerce-clause-looms-over-cannabis-marketplace) - heck, even grain that is made on a farm and used on the very same farm has (in the past) been deemed to influence interstate commerce in [Wickard v Filburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickard_v._Filburn)... that part wasn't overturned.

Comment: “…nothing in the constitution establishes a right to cryptocurrency.”  Correct, but check your default assumption.

Comment: The relevant legal provisions in the U.S. in my mind would be the takings clause and the contracts clause. These would greatly restrict the authority of the government to simply ban cryptocurrencies except prospectively to newly issues coins.